# Multiclick (2 or more button click together)

Tags: android, accessibility, multi-touch, braille, multitouch-keyboard

I want to make an apps like swiftBraille so a blind people can text with braille keyboard (6 button). The problem is only 1 button that I can click at the same time. So, do you know how to make button can be pressed together to give an action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Mohammad, the developer of [SwiftBraille](http://en.swiftbraille.com/) soft keyboard project for blind and visually impaired. In Android and because of the accessibility service, and because of [touch to explore](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006598?hl=en) feature, you can't use multi-touch on the screen while touch to explore is active. All other available Braille soft keyboard requires you to deactivate touch to explore (which is easy using gestures based on the screen reader you're using) to use it as Braille way does. However, that's why Swift Braille is on the board now! To type in Braille way using one hand and one finger by connecting needed Braille dots. The project is Open Source and available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MohammadAlBanna/Swift-Braille-Soft-keyboard/) community, all details shared [here](http://en.swiftbraille.com/blog/swift-braille-project-open-source/).